# Why don't breadcrumbs appear on views generated pages?

Tags: views, theming, breadcrumbs

I'm maintaining a site I didn't build and I'm running into an issue with breadcrumbs. Pages generated by views don't seem to conform to the existing bread crumb system. For example I have a members section page, which has a sub page with a list of links. The links created from basic pages show the correct breadcrumb trail (i.e. home->members->subpage1->subpage2), while the views generated pages only show a breadcrumb trail back to home. So what is causing this? How I work the views pages in the breadcrumb system? Does each views page need it's own template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Views Breacrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_breadcrumb) / [Custom Breadcrubs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) / [Views breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_breadcrumb) modules?

Answer (score 1):

Just so that other people don't run into this issue: I'm using the context module, which lets you sent custom breadcrumbs for each context, supremely useful, better UI than the programmatic approaches.